# Mongoexport not supported?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb and trying to export a collection in json format. When I executed the query which I learnt query from the online manual I get an error.

Input:

```
mongoexport -d test -c Nick -o c:/results.json --journal
```

output:

```
error parsing command line options: --dbpath and related flags are not supported in 3.0 tools.
```

I am not sure how to interpret the output.

I am using mongodb 3.0.4 version. I am implementing the query in command line and not in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

The `--journal` option is the one causing the problem as that option is removed from Mongo 3.0.0 (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#options)

Remove the `--journal` option and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `--journal` flag is not supported `in 3.0 versions`.

The query worked perfectly without the `--journal` option.

Thanks anyway.